# Unity3D select Assets folder according to screen resolution

Tags: unity3d-gui, unity-game-engine

I have made Unity3D game. Background texture is 2048x2048 to fit iPad Retina resolution.
But it is too much for old phones with much less resolution.
I have resized all textures and made a second folder with twice downgraded textures.

What is the correct way to select texture folder according to resolution.

The nature of Unity3D is its GUI tools and if I normally set texture in property inspector then it is not Unity way to set everything manually in code.

Also I am not sure if i will change textures in code then it would not load both old and new textures.

Another idea is to use different scenes for different resolutions. But it doubles work if I wish to change something and it doubles work to test app.

There must be some solution to handle multiple resolutions. But I can't find anything simple that will just selects folder with textures at startup.

Comment: I had the same problem and came down to the conclusion that this can only be done manually in the code too

Comment: It is ridiculous. Everything is so smart in Unity but it lacks such a basic feature.

Comment: You try Sprite Packer ?. Similar to atlas on Ngui

Answer (score 1):

Use the build in settings for texture quality. In the editor see Edit->Project Settings->Quality. You can define the texture resolution in the inspector.
In your project add a small scene prior your first scene and load this first. In here calculate and set the quality level and start the next scene:

```
if (hardware-is-lame)
  QualitySettings.DecreaseQualityLevel();
Application.LoadLevel(...)
```

The trick is that only the texture size reduced version is loaded, you can see that the app uses less memory than normal. The only drawback is that it decreases ALL texture sizes, sometimes I would like to keep the font texture atlas in high res.